# Bootstrap Multiple Modals Trigger right one

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I have a page in my application where there is a bootstrap modal associated with each record that appears. With the current setup I am able to trigger the modal, but it is only triggering the first modal on the page and not the correctly associated modal. I tried some answers on StackOverflow that dealt with multiple modals on a single page, but they didn't work for me.

Here is the link triggering the modal:

```
<td>
    <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#comment-modal" data-actual="{{this.documentRequestIdHash}}" id="record-comment-link">
        {{this.document_request_comments.length}} 
        <span class="fas fa-comment text-primary mr-2"></span>
    </a>
</td>
```

I was thinking I can use the dynamically passed value of `data-actual` to identify the unique modals and associated content.

Here is the modal:

```
<!-- Comment Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="comment-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="commentModelLabel" aria-hidden="true">
...
</div>
```

Here was the jQuery I attempted, but hit an error `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).modal is not a function`:

```
$('#record-comment-link').on('click', function(){
    var commentModal = $(this).attr('data-actual');
    $(commentModal).modal("show");
  })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line:  `var commentModal = $(this).attr('data-actual');` gives commentModel the value of `{{this.documentRequestIdHash}}`. Let's say the value is "modelComment1". 
Then the line:`$(commentModal).modal("show");` Looks for any object with the tag "modelComment1", which it will not find. 
To fix it change the modal html to

```
<div class="modal fade" id="{{this.documentRequestIdHash}}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="commentModelLabel" aria-hidden="true">
...
</div>
```

And the modal show code to

```
$("#" + commentModal).modal("show");
```

That should do the trick

Comment: Hey, thanks for the comment. I gave your suggestion a try, but I still receive the error, `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).modal is not a function`

Comment: Have you added the bootstrap .js before the jquery .js. That can also cause this error.

Comment: That was the issue. Such a simple mistake. Thanks for reminding me.